# Linear search performed over a set of parameters

Tags: python, class, linear-search

I'm generating data of persons looking like that:

```
ID WEIGHT HEIGHT NUM
AB1 76 182 5
30W 98 189 4
AB1 78 187 5
H8J 54 159 5
XSY 98 208 3
```

And I wanna perform linear search over a set of parameters. For example, if my parameters are:

```
["AB1", [76, 78, 98], None, 5]
```

(Parameters after which the search is not performed remain empty (None))

I want to have (for example in new list) person's data who have: ID -> "AB1", weight -> 76, 78 or 98, any height, and num ->5.

So from above generated list I would have:

```
AB1 76 182 5 
AB1 78 187 5
```

Here's how I generate data of persons:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, id, weight, height, num):
    self.id = id
    self.weight = weight
    self.height = height
    self.num = num

  def fun(self):
    return(f"{self.id} {self.weight} {self.height} {self.num}")

def random_id(size = 3, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(size))

def person_data(M):
    persons = []
    for i in range(M):
        persons.append(Person(random_id(), random.randint(50, 120), random.randint(140, 220), random.randint(3, 6)))
    return persons

number_of_persons = 15
def table_of_persons():
    for obj in person_data(number_of_persons):
        print(Person.fun(obj))
```

And this is my function to search for people:

```
def searching_for_person(value):
    s_persons = []
    print(f"Looking for: {value}")
    for i in range(len(value)):
        for obj in person_data(number_of_persons):
            if obj.id == value[i]:
                s_persons.append(Person.fun(obj))

    if len(s_persons) == 0:
        print("No persons")
    else:
        print(s_persons)
```

I have no idea how to write it to make it work well, because now it is returning persons who have id -> "AB1"

How can I fix my function, so its gonna work like I want?

Comment: What is the 'None' value refer to in your list of parameters?

Comment: Have you considered implementing \_\_eq\_\_ in your class? Also, don't use *id* as a variable name

Comment: @Bruno if one of the parameters is 'None' that means I am not searching for this value. For example, if I have [None, None, None, 5], Im looking for persons who have 5 as num

Comment: @AlbertWinestein until now I did not know there was such a thing as __eq__

Comment: With the @AbertWinestein tip you can achieve what you want :) if you struggle just reply it back here, cheers.